# How can I pause/interrupt boost::thread within another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, interrupt

```
void workerFunc()  //first thread
{  
    for (int x=0;x<30;x++) //count up to 29
    {
        cout << x << endl;
        Sleep(1000); //one sec delay
    }
}    

void test()   //second thread
{
    for (int y=30;y<99;y++)  //count up to 98
    {
        cout <<'\t'<< y << endl;        
        Sleep (1000); //delay one sec
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])   
{  
    cout << "Main started " << endl; 
    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);    //start the 1st thread
    boost::thread t1(test); //start the second thread
    cin.get();     
    return 0;  
}
```

Hi, When the thread for `test()` with y=35, I want to pause/interrupt the thread in       `workerFunc()` within thread for `test()`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  (I ask because you probably don't, even though you think you do)

Comment: because in another project i am using a thread to wait for a key to be press which inserts new value to a certain variable. I have a 2nd thread running a constant update screen. therefore if the key is press i want to pause the update screen thread til the value is entered. this is to avoid overlap of cout

Comment: What you actually need is to synchronize `cout`. Just pass boost::mutex to the both thread functions, lock it before `cout` and unlock after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::thread::interrupt`. Your target thread must call one of the [interruption point functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points) periodically, when it's ready to be interrupted. If another thread calls `boost::thread::interrupt`, this functions will throw `boost::thread_interrupted` exception. If your thread are in state, that can't be interrupted but you need to call one of the functions that can be interrupted by `boost::thread::interrupt`, just disable interruption temporarily with [`disable_interruption` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.disable_interruption).

In your case, just replace `Sleep` calls with [`boost::this_thread::sleep`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep) calls.